# Parsing a tab delimited file using Perl regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to figure out how to use regular expressions to be able to "extract" specific text from a tab separated text file and perform operations on the file below.

I have a file that is in the following format:

```
#HEADER_IGNORE        HEADING1     HEADING2      HEADINGN
Some Text Here        value        value2        value3
SOME_TEXTHERE         x                          z
Some More Text Here   A            B
```

And I want to be able to extract the first "column". Essentially, I want to grab all the text before the first tab, so that my regular expression is able to extract:

```
Some Text Here
SOME_TEXTHERE
Some More Text Here
```

I've tried to use the following regular expression without any luck.

```
/(\W\s)*\t$/
```

Now the second thing I wish to be able to do is tell if any row x column reference has a value missing. I.e. In the example file above, the row id `SOME_TEXTHERE` is missing a value for `HEADING2`. There may be an arbitrary number of row ids and columns.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not splitting by tab instead?

Comment: Perhaps you should use `Text::CSV`.

Comment: I have tried splitting by tab but then I just get the whole line split into an array. I began down this road and then it seemed to get complicated as I would not necessarily be able to keep track of the text in the first "column" as there may be N columns.

Comment: @user2402135 The first field will be the first field, whether you use split or a regex, and no matter how many columns you have or missing values.

Comment: Why in the world are you writing code for a problem that has already been well-solved?  **Use existing code that has already been written, tested and debugged.**  The Text::CSV module will do it all for you.

Answer (score 1):

The classical way is to `chomp` each line to remove the line terminator, and then `split /\t/` to extract a list of all the field values.

```
chomp;
my @fields = split /\t/;
my $field1 = $fields[0];
```

However, if you are sure you will only *ever* want the first column, it is simplest to find all the characters at the start of the line that *aren't* tabs.

```
my ($field1) = /\A([^\t]+)/;
```

Given your second requirement, the first of these is best. It depends what you mean by a *"missing value"*, but as long as all the tab separators are there you can check to make sure that a line has a given number of fields by writing

```
my $n = grep /\S/, @fields;
warn "Missing field" unless $n == 4;
```

Or, if you want to discover which field is missing, then

```
my @missing = map { $fields[$_-1] !~ /\S/ } 1 .. 4;
warn "Missing field $missing[0]" if @missing;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments Borodin. In regard to the first part of your answer, would `my $field1 = $fields[0];` not just give me `Some Text Here`?

In answer to your solution for the second problem, I do not know the amount of columns there will be. There may be N columns in the file. By "missing value" I mean blank values. i.e. no text whatsoever. Thanks

Comment: @user2402135: Yes, for the second line of your data file you would get `Some Text Here`. If there are always the correct number of tab separators, then you can just check each value of `@fields` using `/\S/` which will be true if there is any content, or false if the field contains any non-space characters.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a big fan of hash, so I would use hash.
Because `split` doesn't work if the last element in the array is missing, we have to manually add an empty string if the last element is a `\t` (so that the missing column will become an empty string).

You will know which column is missing by checking, for example, if `$rows{SOME_TEXTHERE}[1] eq ""`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(my $first_line = <STDIN>);
my $length = scalar(split /\t/, $first_line);

my %rows;
while (<STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    my @row = split /\t/;
    push @row, "" for 1..$length - scalar @row;
    # Assuming there's ALWAYS a row ID
    my $id = shift @row;
    $rows{$id} = [@row];
}

foreach my $rowID (keys %rows) {
    for (my $i = 0; $i < @{$rows{$rowID}}; $i++) {
        # Column 1 being the id
        printf "missing column #%d in %s\n", $i + 1, $rowID
            if $rows{$rowID}[$i] eq "";
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I adjust the code so that I essentially, use the very first row in the text file which is `#HEADER_IGNORE        HEADING1     HEADING2      HEADINGN`
to count that there are 3 "columns" (Ignore `#HEADER_IGNORE`) and then use the fact that because I have 3 "columns", that each row in the file must have 3 values which are seperated by tabs. 

Therefore, if I had a file that had 8 "columns", it would work in the same manner and iterate the rest of the rows and for each rowID it would expect 8 non-blank values for the 8 "columns".

Thanks!

Comment: I modified the code so that it (probably) does what you want, but in my opinion, I feel like it's relying too much on the correctness of the input. Of course, it's up to you to decide whether you can trust the input or not.